# Java ,Related To scanner

Tags: java, function, integer, java.util.scanner

I have one query regarding `Scanner` in java.

I want to take input from user and perform same operation based on inputs.

If user inputs `1 2` in first line, `3 4 5` in second line, `6 7 8 9` in third line ... so it should call `function(1,2)`; `function(3,4,5)`; `function(6,7,8,9)`; ... based on user input (which are different in parameter size) I want to call same function.

Can anyone suggest me optimal way to do this?

This is my program so far ...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String []args){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int length = sc.nextInt();          // length of array
   int query = sc.nextInt();       // how many queries you want to perform
   int arr[] = new int[length];

   for(int i=0;i<length;i++);
   {
    int arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
     }

   for(int j=0;j<query;j++) { 
    /* here i want to take input from user and if user inputs 2 integer than pass it like function(param1,param2) if he inputs 3 parameter than pass it like function(param1,param2,param3) 

   }
```

Note: For function I am using varargs: `function(int... a)` .

Comment: You've got a typo in this line "for(int i=0;i<length;i++);" . You should remove the last semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Use

> 1. `while(scannerInstance.hasNextLine)` to keep reading input and in the loop
> 2. Use `String value = scannerInstance.nextLine()` to read the entire line
> 3. Then `value.split("\\s+")` to split the input string based on
>      one or more whitespaces.
> 4. Parse each string as an Integer using `Integer.toString()`.
> 5. Pass the integers got in step 4 to your method.
> 6. End while loop.